# how kill mysqld started by mysqld_safe on mac

Tags: mysql

Anyone knows how to kill mysql started by mysqld_safe on mac. I tried the following commands, but none of them works:

1) mysqladmin shutdown,
2) kill -9 $pid_of_{mysqld_safe}
3) MYSQLCOM shutdown

please help! thanks,

Comment: _none of them works_ -- _why_ don't they work? What error messages did you get? Copy and paste the commands and their outputs...

Answer (score -1):

With help from my colleague, I solved the problem with "launchctl unload"